# C# Form: Crosshair in-game

Tags: c#, winforms, directx

I am trying to make easy D3D-liked crosshair In-game with C# form. I managed to get a crosshair in my screen on TOPMOST. But when I open the game(Directx games), it's dissappear(Of course , it's just a form).
I need this in c#

So any of you know any simple trick in C# that can bring my form on top of directx games?
So hard D3D coding wouldn't be that nesscesary.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think you can override the ACTUAL games graphics with GDI+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about overriding the [graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
// Sample height & width
int screen_width = 500;
int screen_height = 500;

// Your image..
var crosshair_bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("C:\Example\CrosshairImage.png");

Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Process.GetProcesses("Example")[0].MainWindowHandle);
g.DrawImage(crosshair_bitmap, new Point((screen_width - crosshair_bitmap.Width) / 2, (screen_height - crosshair_bitmap.Height) / 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably draw your crosshair as a 2d sprite inside the directX control (as 2 textured tringles using UV mapping or through tlan API like XNA's SpriteBatch).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will give it a try.But my maingoal is in c#, because I am also trying to make a d3d-liked menu in c# too.

Comment: Xna is c# platform.. as well as unity and many other, most of them use d3d in order to ease on you dev process

Comment: Sorry, haha I'm new to programming. Anyway,thanks a lot